# Coding google sheets script

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

i work in insurance, and i have a Google Sheets for all my coworkes where i take note of all policies that we make with external collaborations.
I need this: if today a policy expire, the code should send an email to my company addres.
Now the code that i used is working, but it only work for one sheet, and send mail even if he finds black spaces.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO03m.png)

```js
function alertSender() {
  var today = new Date(); 
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
    var cell_date = values[n][5];
    var expired = today > cell_date;
    if (expired) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(values[n][6], 'Mail automatica', 'Servizio scaduto per il sig. ' + values[n][0]);
      Logger.log('Mail inviata all\'indirizzo ' + values[n][6] + ' del sig. ' + values[n][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code i used, where Date (5) is column F and mail (6) is column G.

[Just execution started and execution completed, no errors but no emails, and yes i put in and expired date for test purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLye0.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXgpU5QkV3XlhXh6VMVy_sTeDkXr_Egr9lzhfyno8O4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function alertSender() {
  var today = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[0] != '');
    for (n = 1; n < values.length; ++n) {
      var cell_date = values[n][5];
      var expired = today > cell_date;
      if (expired) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(values[n][6], 'Mail automatica', 'Servizio scaduto per il sig. ' + values[n][0]);
        Logger.log('Mail inviata all\'indirizzo ' + values[n][6] + ' del sig. ' + values[n][0]);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

references

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: i got this "TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(...).getSheets is not a function
alertSender @ Codice.gs:3"

Comment: sorry, I have corrected with getActiveSpreadsheet.

Comment: Now no errors, but no mails either, it does nothing basically

Comment: can you share a minimal repoducible example?

Comment: Edit on OP, just execution started and execution completed, no errors, no emails

Comment: In Column F there are expiry dates for each contract, in column G my mail repeated for each line, ill put sharing link in OP

Comment: Now is sending something. Is sending 3 mails without getting the name for column zero, like "Mister" with no name, and is sending 3 mails even tho there are only 2 expired in the file

Comment: I need to fill column A with just Names (clients)- Mail should be: Object This is an automatic Email.... Client name (from column A) contract is expired (from column F expiry date)

Comment: In the End should be: Column A (if full) client name, column F expiry date (if expired) send a mail to my address in column G, foll all sheets. Other columns are just informations.

Comment: You're the best, seriously, i just resolved a very big problem for me, thank you very much!

Comment: What if i want that var expired = today > (cell date minus 15 days) ?

Comment: No errors but not working. I'm sorry man but i'm fine tuning it on the go and might be needed from other peoples: i need the option to send the mail 15 days before the expiry date column [5].  So maybe should be (expiry-15 days) > today

Comment: For anyone who needs this, seems to work with: var expired = (cell_date - 15) > today;

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, my answer should be +15 instead of -15. Gald to see that you have found another working solution. I apologyze.

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something. I'm not getting emails. Also, does Google translate work on the script or will it break the script?

> MailApp.sendEmail(values[n][6], 'Mail automatica', 'Servizio scaduto per il >sig. ' + values[n][0]);
> Logger.log('Mail inviata all'indirizzo ' + values[n][6] + ' del sig. >' + values[n][0]);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).